# How to handle interface for onActivityResult Override Method

Tags: android, android-intent, interface, adapter

I want to use onActivityResult method in Adapter but after searching on Stack Overflow I found I have to make interface for onActivityResult but I donot know how to make this and handle onActivityResult Methode to work as per my need.

Here is my Adapter Class.

```
    public class PosterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PosterAdapter.PosterViewHolder> {


    private static final String TAG = "resPoster";
    private ArrayList<Poster> posterArrayList;
    private Context context;



    public PosterAdapter(ArrayList<Poster> posterArrayList, Context context) {
        this.posterArrayList = posterArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PosterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.sending_image_layout, viewGroup, false);

        return new PosterViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PosterViewHolder posterViewHolder, int i) {

        posterViewHolder.imageViewDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                posterViewHolder.relativeLayoutImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(posterViewHolder.relativeLayoutImage.getDrawingCache());
                posterViewHolder.relativeLayoutImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/providers");
                dir.mkdirs();
                String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                Log.d(TAG,"filename: " +  fileName);
                File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
                Log.d(TAG,"outFile: " +  outFile);
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        posterViewHolder.imageViewEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setType("image/*");
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
//                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "CHOOSING INTENT"), 0);
            }
        });



    }





    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posterArrayList.size();
    }

    public class PosterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutImage;
        ImageView imageViewBg, imageViewEdit, imageViewDownload, imageViewShare;
        CircleImageView imageViewProfie;

        public PosterViewHolder(@NonNull View posterView) {
            super(posterView);

            relativeLayoutImage = posterView.findViewById(R.id.image_relative);
            imageViewBg = posterView.findViewById(R.id.image_bg);
            imageViewProfie = posterView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile_moving);
            imageViewEdit = posterView.findViewById(R.id.edit_image);
            imageViewDownload = posterView.findViewById(R.id.download_image);
            imageViewShare = posterView.findViewById(R.id.share_image);

        }
    }

}
```

and I want to use this class

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            final Uri selectedUri = data.getData();
            if (selectedUri != null) {
                startCrop(selectedUri);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot retrieve selected Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            handleCropResult(data);
        }
    }
    if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        handleCropError(data);
    }
}
```

Please Help me handle this method in interface.
Thank you.

**UPDATE: **

Here is my activity code to understand more my question.

```
     RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ArrayList<Poster> posterArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PosterAdapter posterAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sending_image);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_poster);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


        getAllPoster();
    }

    private void getAllPoster() {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("poster_id", "1");

        Log.d(TAG + "pp", String.valueOf(params));




        String Url = Constants.Base_URL + "poster/";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Url,  new JSONObject(params),
                response -> {
                    Log.d("responsePending", String.valueOf(response));

                    try {
                        String statusResponseObject = response.getString("status");
                        String msgObject = response.getString("msg");

                        if (statusResponseObject.equals("200")){

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("response");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject pendingFragResponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String posterObject = pendingFragResponse.getString("poster");
                                String positionObject = pendingFragResponse.getString("position");
                                String sizeObject = pendingFragResponse.getString("size");
                                String txt_positionObject = pendingFragResponse.getString("txt_position");
                                String titleObject = pendingFragResponse.getString("title");
                                String descriptionObject = pendingFragResponse.getString("description");


                                //

                                posterArrayList.add(new Poster(posterObject, positionObject,
                                        sizeObject, txt_positionObject,
                                        titleObject, descriptionObject));
                                posterAdapter = new PosterAdapter( posterArrayList, SendingImageActivity.this);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(posterAdapter);
//                                wp10ProgressBar.hideProgressBar();
//                                wp10ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }
                            posterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                            wp10ProgressBar.hideProgressBar();
                        }else {
//                            wp10ProgressBar.hideProgressBar();
//                            wp10ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(SendingImageActivity.this, msgObject, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Server didn't response, Try after some time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }



                }, error -> {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG + "error", String.valueOf(error.getMessage()));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Server didn't response, Try after some time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }




}


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Server didn't response, Try after some time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }



                }, error -> {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG + "error", String.valueOf(error.getMessage()));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Server didn't response, Try after some time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }




}
```

Comment: The onActivityResult() method has to be implemented in the activity. When you are starting a new activity you are casting the context into an Activity, son that activity is the one that is receiving the onActivityResult(). Now make that activity communicate with the adapter.

Comment: @juancamilo87 that is my point I have a activity for adapter but I am unable to communicate with adapter. can you please help me to make this It is a very greatful for me.

Comment: It's hard without seeing the activity code. But in short, make the adapter an attribute in the class so in the onActivityResult() you have access to it and don't have to create it again. To communicate you can either make a public method in the adapter that you directly access, or use interfaces to communicate between them.

Comment: wait I update my answer with my activity.

Comment: @juancamilo87 bro I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Interface` pattern just create public method inside your adapter and call that method when your `onActivityResult` hits in `Activity`.

(This answer is just a workaround for your scenario. Ideally you should not pass your activity `Context` to your adapter, rather than use `Interface` pattern and receive callback inside your activity whenever any action took place (like clicking on edit button) inside your activity and pass relevant data while trigger callback from your adapter.)

You can refer AllNoteActivity and NoteAdapter for reference [here](https://github.com/pratikvar/Note_app/tree/master/app/src/main/java/co/skybase/noteapp/views)

Comment: Sorry bro but I am not  find anything which is useful for me can you please update for me with a code to understand more.

Comment: Reference link has a very straight forward java code and if you know about interfaces then you will surely understand it.
Else you should learn about interface pattern in Java ones

Comment: Bro in my question I am clearly mention that I donot know about interface. So I am asking here. If I know about interface so stackOverflow have sufficient answer for my question.

Comment: Ok. So i will suggest you to try learning about Interfaces as I mention in my earlier reply.

Comment: Sorry bro but I am learning about interfaces but I donot enough time I have to finish this for company

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is put the current method onActivityResult() from PosterAdapter to the activity. Then make the methods startCrop(), handleCropResult() and handleCropError() public (I assume are in PosterAdapter).

In the onActivityResult() change the call of startCrop() to posterAdapter.startCrop(). Same for the other methods. And that should do it.

Comment: I want when I click on Image view and get image from gallery and crop in onActivity result method after that set on imageview. Bro I cant do  as you say because all cropping methods depends on Activity results

Comment: From what I see you have an activity that has an adapter that shows a list of elements.  When an item is clicked, an image chooser is opened. When the user chooses the image, the onActivityResult in the activity will be called with the information. That information can now be used to crop the image and put it in the adapter. If you need to put the image in the tapped item in the adapter then you need to keep track of what was clicked so you can select it afterwards.

Comment: I know that as per same about logic I am clearly mentioned that I am unable to implement that I want answer with code to see that How to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in adapter

In your adapter class

```
    public void waterverYouWantMethod(){

}
```

And call that method from Activity when onActivityResult mehtod called.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   // call that method here
adapter.wateverYouWantMethod();


    }

    }
```